# Octave nested functions "not implemented" error

Tags: matlab, octave

My octave constantly reports me error:

```
nested functions not implemented in this context
>>>   function nested1

nested functions not implemented in this context
>>>   function nested1
```

as a reaction to following code (file named test.m):

```
clear -all;
clc;

function test
  function nested1
    disp('nested 1')
  end

  function nested2
    disp('nested2')
  end

  nested1()
  nested2()
end
```

I just don't get it. What's wrong?

Comment: Not sure if this is implemented in octave but in matlab you can use inline function `nested1 = @()(disp('nested 1'))`, this is for short functions. For longer function why not just define them as completely separate functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, actual problem was that I had this code written in script file. What I really had to do is to turn it into function file.

So. Buggy code looks like this:

```
clear -all; 
clc;

function test
  function nested1
     disp('nested 1')
  end

  function nested2
     disp('nested 2')
  end

   nested1
   nested2
end
```

and working one is

```
function test
  function nested1
     disp('nested 1')
  end

  function nested2
     disp('nested 2')
  end

   nested1
   nested2
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code below:

```
function test
   nested1
   nested2

   function nested1
      disp('nested 1')
   end

   function nested2
      disp('nested 2')
   end
end
```

Comment: Well, now nested is undefined. Which is quite obvious.

Comment: Unfortunately don't owe MATLAB license but all nested function samples at MATLAB is calls first. See [here](https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/nested-functions.html) for same example. Are you sure still getting "nested is undefined ?" because in that case MATLAB samples will be bad :( which can't be true :)

Comment: I'm actually working in octave. So it might be not implemented yet.

Comment: Octave do have [nested functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Nested-Functions.html). You may try examples on [this link](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Nested-Functions.html). Hope it works for you.

Comment: I meant that the way of declaring function after their usage might not be implemented. There are some differences still. And the problem itself is solved already. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The packages load and all the Octave/MATLAB initialize/ending functions are inside the main function, your code will be:

```
function test
  %%packages load below:

  %%initialization/ending functions here:
  clear -all; 
  clc;

  function nested1
     disp('nested 1')
  end

  function nested2
     disp('nested 2')
  end

   nested1
   nested2
end
```

Comment: Don't call `clear` inside a function. The only variables declared at the top of a function are the input variables. This is really bad form.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Cris, I have tried to let the `clear` outside a function, but I receive the same error message said by the author: `nested functions not implemented in this context,  function nested1`, and I was stuck on how to handle it. And when I let `clear` inside, the error went out I don't know why. How could I handle this problem without let the `clear` inside it and making this test function as a main one.

Comment: You don’t need `clear`, a function starts with a clear workspace.